# How can show the datetime with specific pattern n sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of type `datetime` in SQL. The date is "2017-09-07 00:00:00.000". 
I want the output is "9/6/2017 12:00:00 AM"

I used the below script but the output is '    9/    7/    2017' has a lot of space. Would someone help me to modify it

```
SELECT 
    STR(DATEPART(MONTH, SDATE)) + '/' + 
    STR(DATEPART(D, SDATE)) + '/' + 
    STR(DATEPART(YYYY, SDATE))  
FROM
    t 
WHERE 
    t.id = 1234
```

Comment: Answers may be dependent on database engine features.  What SQL database engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SQL Server

```
Select substring(replace('/'+convert(varchar(10),GetDate(),101),'/0','/'),2,10)
```

Or using Format() if 2012+

```
Select Format(GetDate(),'M/d/yyyy')
```

**Format()** has some great functionality, but it is not known as a performer

**Both would return**

```
9/7/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server, you could use the style option in the `CONVERT` function. See here for a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

There doesn't seem a be a style which matches exactly what you want, but you could perhaps combine a couple: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@the_date,101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,@the_date,108)`